# Computing every $P(B)$ in terms of the probabilities $f_X(x)=P(X=x)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma, P)$ be a probability space.

Let $X:\Omega\mapsto E$ be a discrete random variable, with $E\subset{\rm I\!R}$.

Furthermore, let $f_X:E\mapsto[0,1]$ be a probability mass function.

Lastly, let $A\subseteq \Omega$ be a subset of $\Omega$.

I think that the following holds:

$$\sum_{X^{-1}(\{ x \} )\in A}f_X(x) = P(A)=P(X^{-1}(\{ x \})\in A)$$

But at my university the professor defines it like this:

$$P(A)=P(X\in A)=\sum_{a\in A}P(X=a)$$

I think the above scenario is not possible, because we know that

$P(X=a)\Leftrightarrow P({s\in \Omega:X(s)=a })$

so $a\in E$ which leads to  $a\notin A$ and the summation would not be possible.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $\sum_{X^{-1}(\{x\})\in A}$ mean? Usually, the form of a sum like that is $\sum_{s\in S}g(s)$, but you've placed a particular value $X^{-1}(\{x\})$ where the variable should go and worse, the summand isn't a function of that set. Do you maybe mean $\sum_{x\in X^{-1}(\{x\})}$ instead?

Comment: $X^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a subset of $\Omega$. It is the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}$. How can it belong to $A$ wich seems to be a subset of $E$? And finally: what is set $S$? It seems to come from nowhere.

Comment: The line of the prof should be something like $P_X(A)=P(X\in A)=\sum_{a\in A}P(X=a)$ where $P_X$ denotes a probability on $E$ induced by rv $X$. Here $P$ and $P_X$ must not be confused with eachother.

Comment: @drhab, yes you are right, I have fixed it, sorry.
Also thanks for $P_X$, it makes everything clearer now.

But the set $A$ is a subset of $omega$. I should have been more clear.

Milo I thought $X^-1( \{ x \}$ means all values in $A$?

Comment: But the set $A$ is a subset of $\omega$. I should have been more clear.

Comment: To sum up what I understand of the discussion above, your professor explained that, for every $B\subseteq E$, $$P_X(B)=P(X\in B)=\sum_{a\in B}P(X=a),$$ which is quite correct, while you are asking some formula giving $$P(A)$$ for every measurable $A\subseteq\Omega$. In general, $P(A)$ cannot be expressed in terms of the family $(f_X(x))_{x\in E}$, where $f_X(x)=P(X=x)$ for every $x$ in $E$. Consider for example $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$, $X:\Omega\to E=\{0,1\}$ with $X(a)=X(b)=0$, $X(c)=1$, and $A=\{a\}$. There is no way to express $P(\{a\})$ in terms of $f_X(0)=P(\{a,b\})$ and $f_X(1)=P(\{c\})$.

Comment: Correction: for every *measurable* $B\subseteq E$.

Comment: Thank you very much, everybody!